# Using File Names in WiX

Tags: wix

I am copying a file to a directory, and then setting an environment variable to point to that file.  This is working, however, I have to hard code the name of the file (I can't reuse what I already have).  Here is the example:

```
<Directory Id="CUSTOM_DIRECTORY" Name="Directory">
   <Component Id="Framework" Guid="YOURGUIDIDHERE">
      <File Id="FrameworkJAR" Name="framework.jar" DiskId="1" Source="framework.jar" KeyPath="yes" />
      <Environment Id="FrameworkVar" Name="CLASSPATH" Action="set" Permanent="no" Part="last" System="yes" Value="[CUSTOM_DIRECTORY]framework.jar" />
    </Component>
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

As you can see, in the Value attribute, I can type [CUSTOM_DIRECTORY] which will give me the full path of the directory, but I still have to manually type out framework.jar.  Is it possible to just use something like **Value="[FrameworkJAR]"** to get the full install path of the JAR file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is :)

See the documentation on the [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609(VS.85).aspx) data type. Simply use...

```
Value="[#FrameworkJAR]"
```

From the documentation:

> ... If a substring of the form [*#filekey*]
>   is found, it is replaced by the full
>   path of the file, with the value
>   *filekey* used as a key into the [File
>   table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596(VS.85).aspx). The value of [*#filekey*] remains
>   blank and is not replaced by a path
>   until the installer runs the
>   [CostInitialize action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368050(VS.85).aspx), [FileCost
>   action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368589(VS.85).aspx), and [CostFinalize action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368048(VS.85).aspx). ...